# Как сгруппировать <li> в спойлер на js или jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. В общем, есть такой html:

```
<li>310_Васильев.А.А.</li>
<li>310_Иванов.Г.Г.</li>
<li>310_Новиков.С.С.</li>
<li>310_Баринова.Ю.М.</li>
<li>215_Белов.В.П.</li>
<li>215_Путин.В.В.</li>
```

...
Их много...
Как можно сгруппировать данные элементы по первым символам в названии в так называемый спойлер, чтобы по щелчку список с подходящими элементами раскрывался?

То есть примерно что-то такое:

```
<ul>
<li onclick="$('#310').slideToggle('slow');" href="javascript://">Кабинет 310</li>
<ul id="310" style="display: none;">
<li>310_Васильев.А.А.</li>
<li>310_Иванов.Г.Г.</li>
<li>310_Новиков.С.С.</li>
<li>310_Баринова.Ю.М.</li>
</ul>
<li onclick="$('#215').slideToggle('slow');" href="javascript://">Кабинет 215</li>
<ul id="215" style="display: none;">
<li>215_Белов.В.П.</li>
<li>215_Путин.В.В.</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: А в чём сейчас проблема? структура описанная вами и так работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при условии того, что ваш желаемый результат не особо то валидный html,то пример построения списка может быть следующим.

```js
$(function(){
   $("#src-list li").each(function(idx, li){
      var txt = $(li).text();
      var data = txt.split('_');
      var cNum = data[0];
      var name = data[1];
      
      var cId = "#cab-" +  cNum;
      if($(cId).length == 0){
         $("<ul>").attr("id", "cab-" + cNum)
                  .appendTo("#result")
                  .append($("<li>").addClass("toggle").text(cNum)) ;
      }
      $("<li>").text(name).appendTo($(cId));            
   });    
   
   $("#result").on('click', ".toggle", function(){
      $(this).nextAll().toggle();
   });
});
```

```css
li.toggle { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="src-list">
  <li>310_Васильев.А.А.</li>
  <li>310_Иванов.Г.Г.</li>
  <li>310_Новиков.С.С.</li>
  <li>310_Баринова.Ю.М.</li>
  <li>215_Белов.В.П.</li>
  <li>215_Путин.В.В.</li>
</ul>

<hr/>

<ul id="result">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас хороший код. Могу предложить как его улучшить.

Сейчас вы в каждую такую функцию передаёте id, поэтому вызовы везде разные. Можно же вообще ничего не передавать, а получать ul как следующий элемент. Тогда везде будет одна и таже функция.

```
function Toggle() {
   var ul = this.nextSibling;
   if(ul.style.display == "none") {
      ul.style.display = "block"
   }
   else {
      ul.style.display = "none";
   }
   return false;
}
```

Далее все функции можно прямо в HTML коде повесить

```
<li onclick="Toggle()">Кабинет 215</li>
```

Или через JavaScript код
HTML:

```
<li class="spoiler-link">Кабинет 215</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("spoiler-link");
for(var el of els) {
   el.addEventListener("click",Toggle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за помощь!! К сожалению, от своего кода пришлось отказаться, потому как элементы li подгружаются динамически из базы данных, сплошняком. Распределить их по контейнерам `<li onclick="Toggle()">Кабинет XXX</li>` как раз и заключалось основной проблемой.

Отдельное спасибо teran! Внес небольшие коррективы в его скрипт. Ну точнее адаптировал под свои нужды. Единственное, что мне не понятно это замена элементов на jquery. Я сделал просто `$("#src-list").empty();` в самом конце скрипта. В целом, работает, но правильно ли это?
Вот полный html:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#src-list li").each(function(idx, li){
   var html = $(li).html();
      var txt = $(li).text();
      var data = txt.split('_');
      var cNum = data[0];
      
      var cId = "#cab-" +  cNum;
      if($(cId).length == 0){
         $("<ul>").attr("id", "cab-" + cNum)
                  .appendTo("#result")
                  .append($("<li>").addClass("toggle").text("Кабинет " + cNum)) ;
      }
      $("<li>").css({"display":"none"}).html(html).appendTo($(cId));            
   });    
   
   $("#result").on('click', ".toggle", function(){
      $(this).nextAll().toggle('normal');
   });
   $("#src-list").empty();
});
</script>
<style>
li.toggle { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
</style>
<ul id="src-list">
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=208_Жукова.Т.С.">208_Жукова.Т.С.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=208_Лахаткина.А.Л.">208_Лахаткина.А.Л.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=208_Мишулина.Ж.В.">208_Мишулина.Ж.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=208_Моисеева.Т.С.">208_Моисеева.Т.С.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=208_Никитина.О.Н.">208_Никитина.О.Н.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=208_Румянцева.О.А.">208_Румянцева.О.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=209_Афанасьева.М.В.">209_Афанасьева.М.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=209_Бакулина.О.А.">209_Бакулина.О.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=209_Баранова.Л.В.">209_Баранова.Л.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=209_Лукьянова.В.А.">209_Лукьянова.В.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=209_Фокина.Г.Г.">209_Фокина.Г.Г.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=209_Хлюстова.А.Н.">209_Хлюстова.А.Н.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Абносова.Е.В.">210_Абносова.Е.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Афонина.Т.А.">210_Афонина.Т.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Борисова.О.А.">210_Борисова.О.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Грушина.О.И.">210_Грушина.О.И.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Дворникова.А.В.">210_Дворникова.А.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Карцева.Е.А.">210_Карцева.Е.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Коршунова.В.В.">210_Коршунова.В.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Курина.Д.М.">210_Курина.Д.М.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Лихова.И.В.">210_Лихова.И.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Мозголова.Н.А.">210_Мозголова.Н.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Новикова.М.Н.">210_Новикова.М.Н.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Павличук.А.Н.">210_Павличук.А.Н.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Петунина.Н.М.">210_Петунина.Н.М.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Прокофьева.М.А.">210_Прокофьева.М.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Тимофеева.Е.В.">210_Тимофеева.Е.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Трофимова.О.Г.">210_Трофимова.О.Г.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Чигорина.Е.А.">210_Чигорина.Е.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=210_Шило.Е.Ф.">210_Шило.Е.Ф.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=217_Валерьянова.Л.В.">217_Валерьянова.Л.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=217_Генш.М.В.">217_Генш.М.В.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=217_Кржижановский.М.Е.">217_Кржижановский.М.Е.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=217_Филиппова.С.А.">217_Филиппова.С.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_КарасевВА">301_КарасевВА</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_КлоповаТО">301_КлоповаТО</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_КовалеваЮО">301_КовалеваЮО</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_МаксимоваАА">301_МаксимоваАА</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_Младова ЮА">301_Младова ЮА</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_ТелегинаВА">301_ТелегинаВА</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_ТепловаНС">301_ТепловаНС</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_ФотинаКВ">301_ФотинаКВ</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=301_ШуралеваНВ">301_ШуралеваНВ</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=321_Белов.К.А.">321_Белов.К.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=321_Игнатьева.Н.С.">321_Игнатьева.Н.С.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=321_Мелкова.А.А.">321_Мелкова.А.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=321_Рушнов.И.А.">321_Рушнов.И.А.</a></li>
<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=321_Свистунова.С.В.">321_Свистунова.С.В.</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="result">
</ul>
```

PS: У меня есть еще некоторые `<li>` не подходящие под общую группировку, например `<li><a href="chatsb.php?client=!Программисты!">!Программисты!</a></li>` можно ли как-нибудь их исключить из обработки данным скриптом? Пусть будут они необработанные, отдельно...

UPD Проблема решена. Сделал проверку переменной cNum на наличие текста

```
if(isNaN(cNum)){

         $("<li>").html(html).appendTo("#result");
         }else{
          var cId = "#cab-" +  cNum;
       ...
          $("<li>").css({"display":"none"}).html(html).appendTo($(cId));            

    }
```